Solution of Sturm-Liouville Problem with variable coefficients
I am reading a paper and the authors solve the Sturm-Liouville equation
$$(a^2-1)Q''(a) + \left(\frac{8}{3}a - \frac{2}{a}\right)Q'(a) + \frac{4}{9}Q(a)=0$$
on $0\le a<1/2$.
They claim that the two linearly independent solutions are
$$\phi_{\pm}(a) =a^{-1}(1\pm a)^{2/3}$$
but don't provide a proof. How can I derive the two solutions? Note that the derivatives are understood in the classical sense and I am looking for classical solutions.
EDIT: I would like to understand how to derive these solution-without using a CAS, if possible.

See my edits in the post.

Thanks, that clears it up, but with my comment about the lizard people i wanted to prompt you to share the name and authors of the paper (preferably with a link as well if it is freely available), i was aware that you were refering to the authors with "they".

To prove they are solutions, just sub them back in. If your question is how they discovered these solutions, the answer is that they probably used a CAS.

@Moo The initial conditions are irrelevant for the question (I believe) as I am simply looking for the two linearly independent basis solutions. Correct me if I'm wrong.

@K.defaoite Yes, I am wondering how they discovered and how I could proceed given a similar but different equation without using a CAS.

Expand $\phi$ in a series $$\phi = \sum_{k \ge 0} c_{k} a^{k}$$

My best guess is the Frobenius method. But it's not very important. The important thing is to verify that they actually are solutions.
